# Code-writing techniques and best practices for "drop frame" debugging?

Tags: java, debugging

Let's say I'm developing a software that has to retrieve a big amount of data through the API of a webplatform and the API calls are daily-limited.

The softwares has to:

- download records from the platform using, for example, 1000 API requests (limit is 5000)
- compare downloaded records inside an SQL database
- update the webplatform using the APIs making, for example, other 1000 requests

When I'm debugging, I can't afford to re-run the software everytime I find a bug or I would be able to test it just 2 or 3 times a day.

Assuming that **I have** to retreive all the records for testing *(so I can't, for example, export the downloaded content and import it at the next run and save my API requests)*, I'd like to debug the software once without losing the records I've downloaded during the session and **without stopping my debug session**.

The only method that comes to my mind is to **add breakpoints in the main parts of my software** and to use **drop frames** when I have to step back.

## That's how I usually do

#### MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // ...
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> records = MyApiHandler.getRecords();
        Comparator.compareRecords(records); // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

#### Comparator.java

```
public class Comparator {
    public static void compareRecords(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> records){
        // ... after comparation, I have a "Result result"
        UploadResults.uploadResults(result); // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

#### UploadResults.java

```
public class UploadResults {
    public static void uploadResults(Result result){
        // ...
        MyApiHandler.updateRecords(result); // breakpoint here
    }
}
```

This technique allows me to re-write pieces of code without stopping the debug.

For example, if there is any problem in the `Comparator` class, I can make every modification I need in that class, **recompile** it, **drop the frame** (in this example) `Comparator.compareRecords()` and "step back" at the previous class `MainClass` without losing the records it downloaded through the APIs, and then **step into** the **recompiled version** of the `Comparator` class.

This works, but the result is to have a **really big amount of classes** just for debugging-purpose and, in the end, I will have to join all the classes together.

**Is there a better way to do this?**

--

edit: I use **Intellij IDEA**

Comment: I would mock the API or set up a test server with dummy data so I don't have to go through all of this.  That's standard practice and while might not solve every problem, it will actually get you quite a lot of work done.

Comment: I would also avoid executing the whole application to debug a comparator. Write unit tests.